# Invalid Syntax in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that will allow a user to input 20 random numbers that will be added to an empty list.  Once it gathers 20 numbers, it'll print the lowest, highest and sum of the numbers.  I keep getting a syntax error on line 5 at user_numbers.append(num_entry) and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

```
user_numbers = []

while len(user_numbers) <= 20:
    num_entry = int(input('Please enter any number.\n')
    user_numbers.append(num_entry)

    if len(user_numbers) == 20:

        low_num = min(user_numbers)
        high_num = max(user_numbers)
        sum_num = sum(user_numbers)

        print('The lowest number in the list is:', low_num, '.')
        print('The highest number in the list is:', high_num, '.')
        print('The sum of the numbers in the list is:', sum_num, '.')
```

Comment: `int(input('Please enter any number.\n')` has one parenthesis feeling very lonely. Nobody finds out till the next line.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for pointing that out to me!!  I didn't realize it shows up on the next line.  Thanks for the tip too!!

Comment: When posting a question about code that isn't working, it's always important to include a tag that indicates the language you're coding in. Please [edit] your post to include that tag. While you're making that edit, you can also include the actual error message you're getting, because *syntax error* is pretty much useless on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python
$ python foo.py
  File "foo.py", line 5
    user_numbers.append(num_entry)
               ^
```

Missing `)` at the end of the line...

`num_entry = int(input('Please enter any number.\n')`